# Do I need to operate my own server to user Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: firebase, firebase-admin

I have a Firebase project for android and am interested in using the Admin SDK, but it seems like this would require operating my own server. I don't want to have my own server operating 24/7 just for my app to work. Do you need to have a server to use the Admin SDK?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the admin SDK in the app, so you need some other environment to run it.  That could be your desktop, laptop, a server, Cloud Functions, or some other cloud-based service.  Just not the app.

Comment: Thanks, but does this mean I need to create and operate some sort of server, or can firebase host this?

Comment: You have a ton of options to choose from, and I listed a few.  Stack Overflow is not a place to get product recommendations.  Since you haven't said what you're trying to accomplish, it's hard to even make a recommendation that's going to work for you.